# Line not rendered with data in variable but rendering with array data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have a method which renders a line graph with Highcharts. The data in the graph is an array in the `avg_rates` variable, which has these values:

```
[0.8936e2, 0.8901e2, 0.9015e2, 0.9043e2, 0.8994e2, 0.9105e2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

When I use the variable it doesn't render the line:

```
f.series(
  name: "Average rates",
  data: avg_rates
)
```

When I use the array it does render the line:

```
f.series(
  name: "Average rates",
  data: [0.8936e2, 0.8901e2, 0.9015e2, 0.9043e2, 0.8994e2, 0.9105e2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
)
```

I have no ideay why this is happening? Here is the method in full:

```
def create_avg_rates_chart(avg_rates)
    months = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','mei','jun','jul','aug','sep','okt','nov', 'dec']
    min = avg_rates[0] - 5
    max = avg_rates[0] + 5

    avg_rates_chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.chart(type: 'line', height: '150', width: '1000')
      f.pane(size: '100%')
      f.colors(['#0092C9'])
      f.xAxis(
        categories: months.map{ |m| [m] },
        labels: {
          style: { "fontSize": "12px" }
        }
      )
      f.yAxis(
        title: {
            text: 0
        },
        min: min,
        max: max
      )
      f.plotOptions(
        line: {
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              padding: 10
          },
          enableMouseTracking: false,
          lineWidth: 4,
          marker: {
            radius: 5
          }
        }
      )
      f.series(
        name: "Average rates",
        data: avg_rates
      )
      f.legend(enabled: false)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Everything looks OK in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/crsn1fvz/

Comment: Have you considered the fact that when you pass `0.8936e2` (`#=> 89.36`) yourself it's converted to a float `0.8936e2.class #=> Float`. Whereas the values in the variable array are represented as `0.8936e2` and are most likely `BigDecimal`s (`BigDecimal.new('89.36') #=> 0.8936e2`)? Try mapping the variable to floats `data: avg_rates.map(&:to_f)`.

Comment: @JohanWentholt that indeed solves the issue, thanks! Can you add it as an answer, then I will give you credit for it.

Comment: @John  I added the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely happens because when you copied the contents from the array variable you don't copy the actual object but just the console representation (aka the result of `#inspect`).

The array `avg_rates` most likely happens to contain `BigDecimal`s:

```
# avg_rates comes in from outside the function, the line below is a mock.
avg_rates = %w[89.36 89.01 90.15 90.43 89.94 91.05 0 0 0 0 0 0].map(&:to_d)
```

These values are represented in the console using the `#inspect` method and produce the following visual output:

```
#=> [0.8936e2, 0.8901e2, 0.9015e2, 0.9043e2, 0.8994e2, 0.9105e2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

This visual output is also perfectly valid Ruby code. However if you type `0.8936e2` into the console you'll instantiate a `Float` and not a `BigDecimal`. This can be seen if you look at the return value of just entering the the representation of the array:

```
avg_rates_repr = [0.8936e2, 0.8901e2, 0.9015e2, 0.9043e2, 0.8994e2, 0.9105e2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
#=> [89.36, 89.01, 90.15, 90.43, 89.94, 91.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

```
avg_rates.map(&:class).uniq
#=> [BigDecimal]
avg_rates_repr.map(&:class).uniq
#=> [Float]
```

As you said the graph doesn't render when using the `avg_rates` variable, but does with the copying the representation. This means that `LazyHighCharts::HighChart` doesn't accept `BigDecimal`s but does accept `Float`s. So your solution should be to convert the values to `Float`s before passing them to the `:data` option of `#series`.

```
data: avg_rates.map(&:to_f)
```